# PWA with React & Django

Tags: reactjs, django, progressive-web-apps, react-typescript

I'm relatively new to web development and I have a PWA question. I have a React project and the PWA can be installed normally if I deploy the frontend project, but I generate a frontend build and leave the folder inside a Django directory, where it forwards requests to index.html. The problem is that after deploying, even though the service-worker and manifest.json are recognized, it is not possible to install the PWA

Can anyone explain why? I would like to be able to install the PWA by just deploying the django project with the react build inside it and not leaving the front and backend in different deploys